# In SQL Server, how to filter union result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `LiveProductStatus`. Based on special criteria I want to filter my that table's data.

Table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LiveCustomerStatus]
(
    [CustomerStatusID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [StatusType] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

This is my SQL query:

```
select * 
from 
    (select * 
     from LiveProductStatus 
     where StatusType = 1 
       and (Status in (1, 2, 3, 4))

     union

     select * 
     from LiveProductStatus 
     where StatusType = 9 
       and (Status in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13))

     union

     select * 
     from LiveProductStatus 
     where StatusType = 17 
       and (Status in (1, 2))) as temp 
where 
    temp.StatusType in (1, 9, 17) 
    and temp.Status in (1, 2, 4, 5)
```

Filter criteria is:

```
StatusType      StatusValue
----------------------------------------------
1               1,2
9               1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
17              1,2
```

Now suppose my `StatusType` is 1, 17, 9, and `StatusValue` are

- 2 for type 1
- 2,3 for type 9
- 1,2 for type 17

Now in my above SQL query, how can I apply this search?

Comment: You know you don't need a union to do this...

Comment: What's the current query result, and what's the expected result?

Comment: can you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: Forgive me for this, but I think that the problem is rather trivial. Perhaps you must study a bit more SQL...

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't apply the filter directly? `where StatusType=1 and StatusValue = 2 and (Status in (1,2,3,4)) ...`?

Answer (score 4):

```
with my_union as
(
  select * from LiveProductStatus where StatusType=1 and (Status in (1,2,3,4))
  union
  select * from LiveProductStatus where StatusType=9 and (Status in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13))
  union
  select * from LiveProductStatus where StatusType=17 and (Status in (1,2))
)

select *
from my_union    
where    (StatusType = 1 and Status =2)
      or (StatusType = 9 and  Status in (2,3))
      or (StatusType = 17 and  Status in (1,2))
```

CTEs are a very elegant way to define a complex data set, like your union, and posteriorly filter it easily (or join it with additional data, group it, etc. ...).

Answer (score -1):

Use `OR`

```
select * 
from (
  select * 
  from LiveProductStatus 
  where (StatusType=1 and (Status in (1,2,3,4)))
  or (StatusType=9 and (Status in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)))
  or (StatusType=17 and (Status in (1,2)))
) as temp 

where (temp.StatusType = 1 and temp.Status =2)
or (temp.StatusType = 9 and  temp.Status in (2,3))
or (temp.StatusType = 17 and  temp.Status in (1,2))
```

If this returns duplicates, add in `DISTINCT`:

```
select DISTINCT *
from (...) as temp ...
```